# Verificando si registro previo ya existe (SQL server 2008 r2 )

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente script com mas de 20.000 registros en cada tabla:

Con fechas de registros de enero a febrero del 2018:

```
INSERT Table_que_usare (Usuario, IDUnica, servidor)
select Usuario, IDUnica, servidor
from table1
```

Con fechas de registros de marzo a mayo del 2018:

```
INSERT Table_que_usare (Usuario, IDUnica, servidor)
select Usuario, IDUnica, servidor
from table2
```

Con fechas de registros de agosto a diciembre del 2018:

```
INSERT Table_que_usare (Usuario, IDUnica, servidor)
select Usuario, IDUnica, servidor
from table3
```

En cada base de datos hay  mas de un usuario repetido, yo quiero saber si hay alguna forma de hacer el select que me revise si el usuario no existe entonces inserte la data y los que no existan TODOS se inserten a exepcion valga enfasis de los repetidos.

NOTA: Tomen en cuenta que las bases de datos vienen de mas de 3000 backups de SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Deberias agregar un unique constraint al campo IDUnica

Comment: Hola, la respuesta se encuentra en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist es la segunda respuesta.
Es fácil de comprender, pero sí necesitas ayuda, avisa !

Answer (score 2):

Lo más óptimo sería de esta manera

```
DECLARE @Tope numeric(18,0)
DECLARE @Ciclo numeric(18,0)
SET @Tope = 0
SET @Ciclo = 0

SELECT @Ciclo=MIN(IDUnica) FROM table1 
SELECT @Tope=MAX(IDUnica) FROM table1 
WHILE @Ciclo<=@Tope
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT usuario FROM Table_que_usare  where usuario IN (SELECT usuario FROM table1 where IDUnica=@Ciclo))
        INSERT Table_que_usare (Usuario, IDUnica, servidor)
        SELECT Usuario, IDUnica, servidor
        FROM table1
END
```

Asumiendo que el campo IDUnica sea numérico, de otro modo tendrías que crear una variable tipo Tabla para insertar nuevamente toda la tabla (tabla1, tabla2 y tabla3) y añadirle un campo numérico que podrías llamar "secuencia"
y luego le insertas los datos precedido con un `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY IDUnica)` y entonces usarías esa variable tipo tabla en el script anterior

Comment: amigo pero la variable NO es nunerica es IMPOSIBLE en que lugar se ve que un usuario se registre con un numero? es de tipo  varchar medio entendi habia votado por que coocastes varchar pero editastes a tipo INT o numerico eso NO sirve asi amiguito me puede explicar si es varchar porfavor por que no entendi bien la sentencia WHILE

Comment: Por eso escribí "asumiendo", si no es numérica, le creas un campo numérico para que sirva de secuencial para poder recorrerla.